# error BC30456: 'VisualBasic' is not a member of 'Microsoft'

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2019

Visual Studio 2019 (Version 16.10.4) don't support Visual Basic in Immediate window.

[image]

How to fix this issue?

Comment: Have you referenced `Microsoft.VisualBasic`?

Comment: Where? In project? Of course. This is VB console application.

Comment: Read the _If you do not see the..._ notes [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/create-a-visual-basic-winform-in-visual-studio?toc=%2Fvisualstudio%2Fget-started%2Fvisual-basic%2Ftoc.json&bc=%2Fvisualstudio%2Fget-started%2Fvisual-basic%2Fbreadcrumb%2Ftoc.json&view=vs-2019) and [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/get-started/visual-basic/tutorial-console?view=vs-2019).

Comment: @dr.null  is this a joke? This project is working. exactly Immediate window is not working.

Comment: Can you show the exact line of code that produces this result?

Comment: ah ... Immediate Window only is not working... then yes, it was a joke. Try the answer below and read the comment before this.

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove and reinstall `C# and Visual Basic` component in 'Visual Studio Installer'.

[image]

Comment: good idea. but I'm everyday writing in C# and VB (more than C#), all working fine except Immediate window with VB.NET

Comment: @Alex Not sure what caused the issue. Try this solution to see if it can help fix it.